# variations on overview: from fifty thousand feet?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, american-english, terminology, business-language

To follow-up on an [excellent](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/16344/395317) related question, what are the varying distinctions between:

> From x feet
>
> x foot view

where `x` is commonly and variously between ten and fifty thousand.

Answer (score 1):

The X is not meant to be relative.  When someone says 'take a thirty thousand foot view' they're not trying to suggest some varying degree of high level abstraction.  The audience has no agreed upon notion of what constitutes a 'twenty-nine thousand foot view'.  The person saying 'thirty thousand foot view' is just saying it's at a high level that leaves out many details.